# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. On android

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I'm only a beginner so please forgive me for asking possibly a stupid question

---

I don't understand the meaning of Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Please can someone teach me why this error is occurring and how to solve this problem.

ThankYou

This is my class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView title;
    Random   random  = new Random();
    int      counter = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup);
        startingUp();
    }

    private void startingUp() {
        Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread         
            public void run() {
                Boolean b = true;
                try {
                    do {
                        counter++;
                        title();
                        sleep(1000);
                        title.clearComposingText();

                    }
                    while (b == true);
                } catch (IntruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                }
            };
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public void title() {
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        switch (random.nextInt(2)) {
            case 0:
                title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                break;
            case 1:
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                break;
            case 2:
                title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                break;
        }
        title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250)));
        title.setTextSize(random.nextInt(55) + 10);
    }
}
```

And this is my LogCat

```
02-20 10:53:19.293: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5816): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-20 10:53:19.303: D/memalloc(5816): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5c914000 size:14135296 offset:10366976 fd:64
02-20 10:53:19.303: E/(5816): Can't open file for reading
02-20 10:53:19.303: E/(5816): Can't open file for reading
02-20 10:53:19.303: D/OpenGLRenderer(5816): Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 10:53:19.373: D/memalloc(5816): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5db58000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:67
02-20 10:53:20.143: W/dalvikvm(5816): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abc210)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3102
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4112)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8639)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8590)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at android.widget.TextView.setGravity(TextView.java:2538)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at com.example.saikoro.MainActivity.title(MainActivity.java:58)
02-20 10:53:20.143: E/AndroidRuntime(5816):     at com.example.saikoro.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:36)
```

Comment: I think you need to learn the concept of UI thread here. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Thank you but what do I need to do to solve this problem do you know?

Comment: I'm sorry I only started using stackoverflow yesterday so I don't really know what going on

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change your `startingUp()` to this.

```
 private void startingUp() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread         
        public void run() {
            Boolean b = true;
            try {
                do {
                    counter++;
                    title();
                    sleep(1000);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        title.clearComposingText();
                    }
                });


                }
                while (b == true);
            } catch (IntruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
            }
        };
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

***You can't modify views from non-UI thread.***

Answer (score 11):

This exception is not coming due to **title.clearComposingText().**
even this line is not useful ,we can remove this line.
This exception is coming in to **title() function because a non UI-Thread is trying to modify view.**
so we need to call this function in  a ***UI Thread or Handler.***

```
private void startingUp() {
        Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread         
            public void run() {
                boolean b = true;
                try {
                    do {
                        counter++;

                        sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                  title();
                                //title.clearComposingText();//not useful

                            }
                        });


                    }
                    while (b == true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                }
            };
        };
        timer.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the text with `title.clearComposingText();` inside the thread because you can only modify views from the UI thread. Use a handler instead and let him change the text.

Answer (score 2):

You should not update textView from thread other than UI thread.You can use asynctask for this.Can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2):

As other people already stated, you cannot modify the UI from a background thread.

You can either use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or use the [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method